# How to get Low / High gas price with ethers.js?

Tags: gas, gas-price

On [etherscan gas tracker](https://etherscan.io/gastracker) there are three gas prices:  Low / Avg / High.

The code `var gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice()` only returns the Avg price. Sometimes I need the Low/High price, how to get them?

Comment: the only way to get low gas price is to send your TX on Saturday morning or Sunday morning of New York time

Comment: just pull the latest block with all the transactions and get the minimum value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the exact data from Etherscan gas tracker you can use their APIs.

Gas Oracle API ([docs](https://etherscan.io/apis#gastracker)):

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=gastracker&action=gasoracle&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

Response:

```json
{
  "status": "1",
  "message": "OK",
  "result": {
    "LastBlock": "12845223",
    "SafeGasPrice": "21",
    "ProposeGasPrice": "24",
    "FastGasPrice": "25"
  }
}
```

Note that the free tier API key has a rate limit of 5 req/s, you might need to cache or upgrade the key for production usage.